# Why Hamcrest's containsInAnyOrder matcher accepts array and not a list?

Tags: rest-assured, hamcrest

I'm using Hamcrest's `containsInAnyOrder` matcher when asserting REST response using Rest Assured. Here's an example of my assertion:

```
assertThat(
        body.jsonPath().getList("zones.name"),
        containsInAnyOrder(values.getName().toArray()));
```

First argument returns a List. Second argument (`values.getName()`) also returns a List. But Intellij IDEA shows an error on a mactcher: *Unchecked generics array creation for varargs parameter*. When I run this assertions, I get `java.lang.AssertionError`. When I convert second argument to an array, like `values.getName().toArray()`, I get everything working as expected.

So I can't understand why comparing a List with a List doesn't work, but List with an array does? Why do I need to convert the second argument to an array?

Answer (score 1):

[`containsInAnyOrder`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/collection/IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.html#containsInAnyOrder(T...)) accepts a `T...`.

When you pass a `List`, you aren't comparing the elements in the `body.jsonPath().getList("zones.name")` to the elements in the `values.getName()`, but to a single-element array that contains the list itself. Since a string cannot be equal to a list, the assertion fails.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry, I can't understand this statement: _a single-element array that contains the list itself_. Could you please explain it a bit?

Comment: Suppose you have a list with `"a"` and `"b"`. When you pass that as an argument you won't get an array with `["a", "b"]`, but an array with `[list("a", "b")]`

Comment: But if I check an actual result which is a List in `body.jsonPath().getList("zones.name")`, why an expected result should be an array and not the same List?

Answer (score 0):

Because there is `Collection` of `Matchers`:

```
public static <T> Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? extends T>> containsInAnyOrder(java.util.Collection<Matcher<? super T>> itemMatchers)
```

You could use something like `containsInAnyOrder(equalTo("bar"), equalTo("foo"))` but it is not so handy.